Start-AVAppCapture and Stop-AVTask
I'm a devops engineer helping our VDI team with some VMWare automation. Basically, we want to deploy our >NET application onto a Capture machine. We use Octopus for all our deployments. The issue that I'm facing right now is that I run Start-AVAppCapture in an Octopus Step, install the application using Octopus in a different step(multiple steps) and run Stop-AVTask in the next step. Since each step runs in a different powershell session, I am unable to create the vhd file successfully. I'm very new to VMWare and AppVolumes. Can someone suggest the best way to go about installing a .NET application into a capture machine through Octopus (or a solution to run Satrt-AVAppCapture and Stop-AVTask in different ps1 sessions)
